# Split String with another String containing \t (tabs)

Tags: c#, database, string, tabs, split

I've rewritten the whole question, because it was very hard to read.

My Goal is to load a sperator for a split operiation out of a database and seperate strings within C# with the loaded seperator.

```
String dbSeperator = "@START@\\t";
String stringToSplit = "@START@\t asdasdasd @START@\t 2242423 @START@\t asdasda";
String[] dbSperatorSplitArray = new String[1];
dbSeperatorSplitArray[0] = dbSeperator;

String seperatedValues = stringToSplit.Split(dbSeperatorSplitArray, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

the above example doesn't work, because the string readed out of the databse doubled the backslash.

The following code is written completely with C# without database access and everything will be fine:

```
String cSharpSeperator = "@START@\t";
String stringToSplit = "@START@\t asdasdasd @START@\t 2242423 @START@\t asdasda";
String[] cSharpSperatorSplitArray = new String[1];
cSharpSeperatorSplitArray[0] = cSharpSeperator;

String seperatedValues = stringToSplit.Split(cSharpSeperatorSplitArray, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

Is there any way to get the `dbSeperator` out of the Database without the additional backslash?

Comment: The question is not clear where do you want to split the string in the database or in your code

Comment: i'am trying to split the string within c#

Comment: I suspect that the problem lies within the escpaed tab character, although without further info we can't be of much help.

Comment: then use String.Split() method...

Comment: addes some example code, in general evberything works fine without databse, afterloading the split string via database splitting doesn't work anymore

Comment: It sounds as if you have stored the slash and t characters in the database rather than the tab character (0x09).  Can you verify the contents of the database field?  Can you show the hex representation of your separator string in the database?

Comment: hi,thx for your hints,... I've checked the database entries and \t was saved. If updated the charcter and everything works fine,....

Answer (score 0):

It will likely be something like this:

```
  String[] split = YourString.Split(new String[] { "@START@\t" },StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

        foreach (String item in split)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item);
        }
```

But hard to say without seeing the code.

Comment: everything works fine and splitting works if I define the splitstring by myself within c#, but loading splitstring withing my splitstringvalue out of databse results in an extra backslash and splitting doesn't work anymore

Comment: Where are you seeing this extra backslash?  In the debugger?  The debugger will show an extra backslash when hovering the mouse over a variable or using a watch.